# Electron app crashes when I ask permission to use camera. Error message asks for string in com.apple.security.device.camera. Shouldn't it be boolean?

Tags: macos, permissions, camera, electron, info.plist

I have an Electron app that needs access to the camera. On Windows it works fine but on MacOS it doesn't and even crashes when I try to ask permisson.

When I call the routine to check the permission status (shown bellow) it gives me a not-determined answer.

```
systemPreferences.getMediaAccessStatus('camera')
```

Then, to ask for permission (and hopefully show the allow/deny pop-up) I use the following:

```
const { systemPreferences } = require('electron')
systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('camera')
```

But when I do, it instantaneously crashes the app and gives me a long detailed crash report that, among other things, says this:

```
This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.
The app's Info.plist must contain an com.apple.security.device.camera key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Additionally, the Info.plist generated in the root of the app instalation has all of the entries needed. I even included the hardenedRuntime as true.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the Camera</string>
<key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
<true/>
<key>hardenedRuntime</key>
<true/>
```

Some final notes...

- I was struggling with app signing and finally made it to use a valid certificate to sign during the build. Before that the app did not crash when I asked for the permission. It simply did nothing at all. The crashing started as soon as I managed to sign the App.
- I'm using electron-builder to build the .dmg and installing from that. `npm run electron:build`. When I run the app in dev mode through `npm run electron:serve` it works perfectly and doesn't even pop the permission pop-up. The access status returns as granted.
- Shouldn't com.apple.security.device.camera be a boolean? Everywhere I read about it it is a Boolean. Although the error message asks me to define a string with a description. (which I already tried and did not change anything)

Any ideas on how to solve that?

I already tried to change the Info.plist mannualy. Didn't work. How can I make sure I'm working on the right Info.plist file. There are a few. The one I was using is the largest and seems to be the main one. The others are helpers.

I also tried to manage the permission in the MacOS System Preferences. Did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **"com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory": true**

```
    mac: {
           ....
          extendInfo: {
            "NSCameraUsageDescription": "some description",
            "com.apple.security.device.camera": true,
            "com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory": true
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Dzho. It did not work. In the meantime, I also tried setting some entitlements (including the one you suggested) and it did not work either. I don't know if the error solution is related to entitlements or maybe the fact that my application starts a lot of processes and maybe the info.plist file is correct but assigned to the wrong process. Since I heavily use the Electron IPC to communicate between the main process and the renderer process. I don't know...

Comment: My same error was that the settings from the plist were not read at all. It was possible to change something only from the json file (in my case, vue.config.js). Check if your plist is not loaded at all.